# How to compare graphs of 2 time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, pose-estimation

I have 2 dataframes containing movements of a person and want to compare how similar they are to each other or to be precise how well is person 2 able to copy person 1.

```
import pandas as pd
fp = pd.read_csv("first_person.csv")
sp = pd.read_csv("second_person.csv")
fp = fp.iloc[: , 1:]
sp = sp.iloc[: , 1:]
#fp.LEFT_SHOULDER_Y.plot(),sp.LEFT_SHOULDER_Y.plot()
```

#This is what i get when i plot against a particular columns
[image]

What is want is a list of graphs one by one against each and every column in the dataframe without manually writing the code for each column.

I tried this

[image]

But this is not what I want, I want individual graphs for individual column.
**Also is there a way I can compare how well is person 2 able to copy person 1.**
Thanks
Links to csv files:

first_person.csv - https://drive.google.com/file/d/10BNGtTY8nu8ww4yVUM5bkg8i4ZBUSOnU/view?usp=sharing

second_person.csv - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RCZ7lbdgTTzgtVPGmLas-7kMTtUOeDXM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried correlation between the two people. I would say that the closer the values are to each other, the better the correlation ??

Comment: Can you please help me with how to get the correlation score.

Comment: ```df['A'].corr(df['B'])``` - find the correlation between column A and column B in a dataframe (df)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ScottC. I searched for more and found out that print(df2.corrwith(other=df1)) does the thing which I wanted specifically. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get separate plots, display each plot inside the loop...

```
import pandas as pd
fp = pd.read_csv("first_person.csv")
sp = pd.read_csv("second_person.csv")
fp = fp.iloc[: , 1:]
sp = sp.iloc[: , 1:]
for x in range(fp.shape[1]):
    fp.iloc[:,x].plot(),sp.iloc[:,x].plot()
    plt.title(fp.columns[x])
    plt.show() ## Added so that each individual plot is shown
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can i get the name of the column it is plotting and do you know any method by which we can compare how well person 2 is able to copy person 1.

Comment: Use `plt.title(fp.columns[x])` inside loop. Code updated in answer

Comment: The answer is 1100% correct, I am waiting if I get some answer on the similarity score.
I will surely close it once I get it done!
Thanks